# How to keep asp.net development server still running?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

How to keep asp.net development server still running?

I'm developing a asp.net mvc project. After I uninstall Resharp. The server will be only launched at debugging.

Is there any way to keep it still running, so I can recompile more effective.

Comment: Recompile doesn't depend on the development server, in general. Are you using a web site "project"?

Comment: Yes, My old project now still meet the same problem.

Comment: Oh, It's a ASP.NET MVC Project. But it's work well before. Now, the server will shut down. Don't know why.

Comment: Is it just this project or does it happen when you create a new boiler plate project?

Comment: Yes, it's MVC, but did you create it using "File->New Project", or "File->New Web Site"?

Comment: I have the same issue, it started this behaviour recently on all of my projects. I'm really annoyed by it! I used to just start/stop debugging once to start cassini, and afterwards just need to compile my classes to see the updated code running. Eventually I could go into debug mode, which would just attach visual studio to the process... It rips my development flow apart.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for the same reason.  I reloaded the settings and everything was fine.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247075(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I did it. But problem still there